# Построчный вывод части списка

Tags: python, строки, list, split

Мне нужно выводить строку слов из списка слов на экран так, чтобы каждое слово в строке было цельным, при этом длина строки, которая будет выведена, не должна превышать 40 символов. Вывести весь список слов построчно.

Например:

```
words = ['Привет', 'Хорошо', 'Классно', 'Автомобильный', 'Слова', 'Строка', 'Идентификация', 'Книга']
```

Вывод:

```
Привет Хорошо Классно Автомобильный 
Cлова Строка Идентификация
```

Я нашел лишь такой способ, но при нем не учитываются пробелы между словами и вывод такой:

```
for index, _ in enumerate(str(words)):
    line = str(words)[index * 40:(index + 1) * 40]
    print(line)

# Вывод: 
['Привет', 'Хорошо', 'Классно', 'Автомоб
иль', 'Слова', 'Строка']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import textwrap

words = ['Привет', 'Хорошо', 'Классно', 'Автомобильный', 'Слова', 'Строка', 
          'Идентификация','Книга']

str_of_words = " ".join(words)
print(textwrap.fill(str_of_words, width=40))
```

---

*Вывод:*

> ```
> Привет Хорошо Классно Автомобильный
> Слова Строка Идентификация Книга
> ```

---

*Объяснение:*

Для таких задач подходит стандартный модуль `textwrap` - см. [textwrap — Обёртывание и заполнение текста](https://digitology.tech/docs/python_3/library/textwrap.html).

1. Сначала сделаем из вашего списка одну строку методом `.join()` - см. [Преобразование списка в строку методом join](https://pythonru.com/osnovy/python-join).
2. Затем к этой строке применим функцию `fill()` модуля `textwrap` с ключевым параметром `width=`, в котором задаем максимальную длину.

Comment: [textwrap — Text wrapping and filling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html).

Answer (score 0):

Просто берите и считайте символы в строке + добавляемое слово + пробел

Вышли за ограничение, выводите и заново добавляйте.

```
words = ['Привет', 'Хорошо', 'Классно', 'Автомобильный', 'Слова', 'Строка', 'Идентификация', 'Книга']

letterInString = 40 # Ограничение длины выводимой строки
stringToPrint = '' # переменная для объеденения слов

for letter in words:
    if len(stringToPrint) + len(letter) + 1 <= letterInString:
        stringToPrint += letter + ' '
    else:
        print(stringToPrint) # Печатаем стороку
        stringToPrint = letter + ' '
        
print(stringToPrint) # Печатаем остаток
```

Если длина строки не должна учитывать последний пробел, то из условия if стоит убрать `+ 1`

Answer (score 0):

Слова обрабатываются последовательно и сразу же печатаются. Обработка первого слова безусловная. При обработке остальных слов требуется решать, что печатать перед словом: пробел или перевод строки:

```
def print_wrap(seq, width):
    it = iter(seq)

    for word in it:                # обработка первого слова
        print(word, end='')
        space = width - len(word)  # остаток места в строке
        break

    for word in it:                # обработка всех остальных слов
        size = len(word)
        if size < space:
            print('', word, end='')
            space -= size + 1
        else:
            print('', word, sep='\n', end='')
            space = width - size

    print()
```